# fork(), sleep(), and pipe(int *fd) in Mac OS X

Tags: c, linux, macos, fork

I am taking a class called 'Operating Systems' and we are learning about these functions. I have a Mac and i want to know if these function work on Mac, or do I have to install linux. If I can't do this on Mac, what linux distribution should I install? (There's so many, I don't know which one to get).

Answer (score 4):

Your prototype for `pipe()` is wrong, but all three functions are part of POSIX. Since OS X is a POSIX operating system, it supports all three. Note that you will need to install Apple's developer tools in order to have access to a compiler and the appropriate headers and such in order to build software that uses them.

Comment: The OP's prototype for `pipe()` is perfectly cromulent.

Comment: It may have the same end result, but many references, [Apple included](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/pipe.2.html), use a slightly different one.

Comment: The declarations `int pipe(int *fd);` and `int pipe(int filedes[2]);` have identical semantics (changing from `int [2]` to `int *` is in this way no different to changing from `filedes` to `fd`, or even leaving out the parameter name entirely).  Neither of them are in any sense wrong.  The worst you can accuse the OPs formulation of being is unconventional.

Answer (score 0):

I just took Operating Systems, and since the course revolves around UNIX, if you were on Windows, I'd recommend installing Linux just for the sake of the course. Since you are on a mac, it shouldn't be too different. By the way, most distros have live versions, so you can just boot up Linux for an assignment or something, if you want. Any popular distro would do just fine.